# Ember save component value (normal saving is no prob)

Tags: ember.js

I am struggeling to get a gridster layout values saved in my model: normal saving isn't that big deal.. just the grid layout.. how to fix this part?

Component: Serialized data availible after resized grid

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagname: "",
  Setupgridster: function(){
    Ember.$(".gridster ul").gridster({
      widget_base_dimensions: [359, 232],
      widget_margins: [5, 5],
      testvalue: 213213,
      helper: 'clone',
      resize: {
        enabled: true,
        max_size: [3, 3],
        min_size: [1, 1],
        stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
          var widget_base_dimensions = this.serialize($widget)[0];
        }
      },
      serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
          return {
            col: wgd.col,
            row: wgd.row,
            size_x: wgd.size_x,
            size_y: wgd.size_y
          };
      }
    }).data('gridster');
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

Save controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  model: 'layout',
  actions: {
    save: function(){
      var newName= this.store.createRecord('layout', {
        title: this.get('title'),
/** Don't know how to get in here serialized gridster data **/
        layout: this.get('gridsterdata')
      });

      newName.save();

      alert('saved');

      this.transitionToRoute('index');

    }
});
```

Someone told me to intergrate the save option into the component itself as an action, but I haven't got a clue how to make this work. Could somebody fix this or make a suggestion. I should be really pleased! (looking allready 1 week on this issue)

Comment: Is there someone who could fix this? I should be very happy!

Answer (score 0):

so you found the gridster resize stop callback, all you should need to do is:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagname: "",
  Setupgridster: function(){
    var _this = this;
    Ember.$(".gridster ul").gridster({
      ...
      resize: {
        stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
          _this.sendAction('save', your_params_here);
          var widget_base_dimensions = this.serialize($widget)[0];
        }
      }
    }).data('gridster');
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

and then in your template where you are using your component, bind the action:

```
{{gridster-component save='save'}}
```

and modify your controller save action to take whatever arguments you send from the component.

Comment: Thank you, the issue with the stop api is: you could only get the resized widget value back. Can you tell me how I could get the whole gridster layout (serialized) data back?